# select by class AND id that has been stored in var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code :

```
$('.more_results').click(function() {
  var userid = $('#userid').text();
  var more = $(this).attr('id');
  $.post('myquests.php', {userid:userid, more:more}, function(html) {
    $(more+".more_results").remove();
    $("#tab1").append(html);    
  });
});
```

my issue is trying to select by the class and the stored id. So it would be like `.more_results#1, .more_results#2`, etc

Comment: `id` attributes consisting only of digits are only valid from HTML5 onwards. Are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a "#" if you want to select by id:

```
$.post('myquests.php', { "userid" : userid, "more" :more}, function(html){
    $("#" + more + ".more_results").remove();
    $("#tab1").append(html);    
});
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question.  Can you edit to make it a bit clearer?

Comment: I think a space is missing.
`$("#" + more + " .more_results").remove();`

Comment: That would mean items with a class of .more_results *inside of* the item of id #more

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select by id or class since you already have a reference to the element you want to remove.

```
$('.more_results').click(function() {
  var userid = $('#userid').text();
  var elementToRemove = $(this);
  var id = elementToRemove.attr('id');

  $.post('myquests.php', {userid:userid, more: id}, function(html) {
    elementToRemove.remove();
    $("#tab1").append(html);    
  });
});
```